# Does SONAR implementation consider accompanying classes as part of the public class - metrics

Tags: java, sonarqube

### Introduction

I'm thinking how I can get past specific critical/major issues without making major refactoring and breaking the comparison with previous revisions (diff etc).

I know I can split my class into multiple classes that are in the same file without breaking the comparisons. I have done this already. **(Will provide an example tonight).**

However, question is: does SONAR consider accompanying classes in the same .java file when running it's algorithms? Does it consider nested classes?

**More importantly does it consider them as part of the key 'public class' that has the same name as the file name. Do the calculations for the various metrics consider them as the `public class` when generating the warnings?**

### Example

of how to refactor code so diff is not majorly broken

I had the following code in a very long chain of `if, else if`:

```
}else if ("cdbStreet".equals(paramKey)) {
```

And converted it into:

```
}else{
        setSearchDataByRequestParametersPart2(searchData, ...);
      }
    }
    return queryString.toString();
  }

  private static void setSearchDataByRequestParametersPart2(SearchRequestData searchData, ...) {
    if ("cdbStreet".equals(paramKey)) {
```

Comment: Where's the [mcve]?

Comment: @Jim Garrison  it is a theoretical problem and practical problem. If I pasted the legacy code I have in front of me, it would be around 2000 lines long. You don't need to see the code if you understand the terminology, problem, and proposed solution I am mentioning. DOES SONAR CONSIDER STATIC ACCOMPANYING CLASSES AND NESTED CLASSES WHEN RUNNING IT's ALGORITHMS?

Comment: Well, the purpose of SO is to be useful to _future_ readers. Solving your specific issue is of secondary importance.  You should provide enough explanation and detail that someone who doesn't share your entire context will be able to understand the question.  Maybe tag it correctly and provide some background.

Comment: In the example I do not see any inner classes. I see some 'extract method/class refactoring, but no inner classes.
Sonar will work perfectly well with both old and new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonar is doing code analysis for nested (inner) classes. It works well for my commercial project (I cannot share example). Violations are reported for inner static and non-static classes.

There are some rules specific to inner classes
https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#q=inner|languages=java

For available example see
https://sonarqube.com/component_measures/metric/lines/list?id=com.icegreen%3Agreenmail-parent

From line 358 you have inner class FetchCommandParser that is analysed. There are a few warnings reported for code in that class.

Internally, sonar plugin works with source code and bytecode. By default **all code** you have is submitted for analysis (you may configure exclusions if you want to).

Comment: What about `static classes` in the same file?